# Having problems logging into instagram using request module Python

Tags: python

```
import requests as s

url='https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/'
data={'username':'****', 'password':'******'}

p=s.post(url, data=data, allow_redirects=True)
to_check= p.text
if('Sorry, your password was incorrect. Please double-check your password.' in >
        print('Password incorrect.')
elif("The username you entered doesn't belong to an account. Please check your >
        print('Username incorrect.')
else:
        print('Unknown error.')
```

Output(For even the right usernames):

Username incorrect.
I am heavily confused can anyone help?

Comment: Just print to_check, and check what is actual response from api?

Comment: You should use the [API](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram) instead of logging in like that.

Comment: Your provided code is also not correct syntactically, Please update it properly

Comment: You also need to understand something every URL is not exposed as API and even if it is API, not every method (POST, GET, etc) are allowed on that. You need to check  https://www.instagram.com/developer/ for more information.

Comment: @ShivamSeth Thank you I will look into it. Also I know it is not correct that's why I came here.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `python-instagram` module to log into instagram instead.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it.